# Why does streaming an MP4 video file from a WordPress site work fine in the browser yet fail when I'm trying to save it to a file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, wget

I am trying to learn more about streaming and why a video that plays fine in the browser is so tricky to download to a local hard drive for offline playing.

It's hosted on WordPress and the full URL looks like this:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/some%20video%20file.mp4
```

When I load the URL into the browser, the full file plays for about 38 minutes, works fine, no problem. It's about 480MB.

However, when I try to "save as" on the video, I only get 11MB.  It allows me to right click, but just doesn't download the full video.

I've tried wget, which is only able to download about 10MB, 1% at a time, each time saying "connection closed" and retrying until it finally gives up after about 10 tries. It does chug away at it, so if I could get it to give up after 100 tries maybe I'd get the whole thing?

I've tried several video downloader tools, all of which fail or only download three or four minutes of the file.

I've tried ffmpeg, which says there's a corrupt header:

```
ffmpeg -i https://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/some%20video%20file.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy some-video-file.mp4
```

I've tried VLC, a variety of ways, none of which seem able to play or convert this file.

The ONLY success I had was with youtube-dl, which would (like wget) only get a 1% chunk, even less, before quitting. But it seemed to build on previous failures and add to partial files, so I used the -R switch and set the retries to 1000 from the default of 10, and let it chug away and this finally got me the file.

I have a feeling that this is a Vimeo file, if that matters, just from the look of the widgets and so on. (Edit: It may not be, based on a comment below.)

It seems so strange that there's not a simple way to get the browser, which plays the file fine, to dump this output that it's putting on the screen to a file.

Thank you in advance for offering thoughts or explanations about the process behind this and why it may be so challenging.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: “I have a feeling that this is a Vimeo file…” But you show a URL that indicates an MP4 file saved on a WordPress site. This is confusing: An MP4 file on a WordPress site is simply a video file stored statically on a WordPress site. A Vimeo video is a file hosted by Vimeo’s vast network of streaming servers. Each one is a different thing to deal with. And if the video file is — in fact — just an MP4 video on a Wordpress site, that would be theoretically easier to deal with.

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, though I'm not saying I'm right and if I wasn't confused, I wouldn't be asking the question.  If an mp4 file can't be a Vimeo file then I'm wrong about that...just thought it might be useful.  Like, if somehow the mp4 URL is a container for a Vimeo-hosted file out there.  I'm probably wrong, just thought it might be a useful clue.  If not, no worries and sorry to add extraneous info that's not helpful.

Comment: Can you share the actual URL?

Comment: @llogan I don't want to post it but could PM it to you if you want.  (Seems I can't message you directly, but can you message me?)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing a straight passthrough like that there's no reason to use ffmpeg. It's a pure network operation just use wget or equivalent.

wget -o some-video-file.mp4 https://somedomain.com/wp-content/uploads/some%20video%20file.mp4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a year or two late to the party here, but I still thought I'd throw this in for people who find this question in the future.

I would suggest that you might try fooling around a bit with the "Developer Tools" that are present in all of the major web browsers, and that generally have similar features and operation between them. Learning curve is probably a bit steep, but will likely be a nice skill to have in the long run. However, even just poking around and doing some intelligent experimentation can often expose a useful link or other information.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1236462)